# Keeping font of referenced cell on Google Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Photo of current build with deseired result]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYSLT.png)In trying to build a sheet on Google Sheets that automatically takes a given input turns it into a barcode and provides an out put with that barcode.

I can make the bar code with a font option that works for me. However referencing the cell with the barcode only brings over the text.

How can I keep the font of the referenced cell?

I've tried to call the cell but it won't stay as a barcode. I'm hoping to get anyway to automatically generate the desired output.

Comment: Have you consider the setFont methods in Class Range?